# Three.Js: drawImage cuts original png

Tags: canvas, three.js, drawimage

For instance I have a 301x278 png image and I want to draw it like this:

```
    var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

    var texture2 = new THREE.Texture(canvas2);

    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture2, side:THREE.DoubleSide} );

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "test.png";

    imageObj.onload = function()
    {
        context2.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 301, 278)
    };

    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(301, 278),
        material2
    );
```

But unfortunately only a half of the image is actually being displayed. How can I fix it?

Comment: try to add `canvas2.width = 301; canvas2.height = 278;` right after `var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');`

Comment: It works! Awesome, thank you!